# How to do simple client-side form validation using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I was doing a project series on CodeCademy and I got a project in the series to do a client side form validation using JavaScript/jQuery.

My HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Validation</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheet.css' type='text/css'/>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  First Name : <input type='text' id='fname' placeholder='Enter First Name'><br><br>
  Last Name : <input type='text' id='lname' placeholder='Enter Last Name'><br><br>
  Age : <input type='text' id='age' placeholder='Age'><br><br>
  Sex : <input type='radio' class='sex'> Male <input type='radio' class='sex'> Female
 </form>
 <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript/jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 var fname = document.getElementById('fname').val();
 var lname = document.getElementById('lname').val();
 var age = document.getElementById('age').val();
 /*Do not know how to get element by class and that too, two different type. Have to check if user chose anything or not*/

  $("#submit").click(function()
  {
   if(fname.length === 0)
   {
    alert("Please input a first name");
   }
   else if(lname.length === 0)
   {
    alert("Please input a last name");
   }
   else if(age.length === 0)
   {
    alert("Please input an age");
   }
  });
});
```

I don't need a very complicated code and please help me in the HTML department if something is wrong there or if something needs to be added there.

Also, I don't know how to get different elements in a class. I have put a comment in my jQuery regarding that so please help if you can.

This is a problem in a CodeCademy project and this is where a lot of newbies in JS and jQuery have a problem, so if you can help, it'll help a lot of people and not just me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `.value` instead of `.val()` since you're using pure Javascript:

```
var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
```

if you want to use `.val()` method then you need a jQuery object:

```
var fname = $('#fname').val();
var lname = $('#lname').val();
var age = $('#age').val();
```

You also need to put those variables inside `.click()` handler in order to get the updated value of these textboxes, currently you only retrieve the value on page load which is always equal to `0`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
        var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
        var age = document.getElementById('age').value;

        if (fname.length == 0) {
            alert("Please input a first name");
        } else if (lname.length == 0) {
            alert("Please input a last name");
        } else if (age.length == 0) {
            alert("Please input an age");
        }
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5zqW7/)**

Comment: I corrected that but now even if I input the first name it says Please enter a first name.

Comment: Did you check my demo? You need to put the variables inside click handler to get the values inside your textboxes in real time. Please check my answer again.

Comment: Sorry I didn't look at that. And how do I check if the user has ticked either option in sex or not? I don't know how to handle that. There are two options in the same class of both radio type inputs.

Answer (score 0):

from your example, get elements by class name

```
var lists = document.getElementsByClassName("sex");
```

to access specific value use `lists[0].value` it will return "Male" or `lists[1].value` will return "Female"

if you use native/pure javascript use `.value` not `val()` . `val()` is only for jquery

Comment: I want to check if the user has ticked on any of the two or not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're asking a couple questions at once.

As suzonraj, pointed out you need `document.getElementsByClass` to get elements by class name and as Felix pointed out, you need to place your data look up inside your `.click` event in order to get the current, not page `.ready` value.

I will add that you should add the `name` parameter to your radio boxes, so they actually function like radio boxes - turning one off when another is clicked. With this, you could use `document.getElementsByName`, which is really what you're after with a radio collection.

As far as validation, you would then need to go through your array of elements by name or class, and then validate that at least one is `.checked`.

Here is an example based off the code Felix shared: http://jsfiddle.net/5zqW7/8/

One addition, is that validation occurs for all elements rather than just until the first element that fails. This is a little more communicative to the user, as it will identify all the wrong fields, not just the first, hit submit, then the second, and so on. In a real form, you'd probably have something less loud than an `alert()` anyhow. That may not be necessary for your assignment.

Comment: what does this line mean? (!current.checked && i == (len-1) ?

Comment: That's checking two things. First, if we DON'T have a checked radio and we just hit the last element in the list. In other words, we went through the whole list and on the last item, we still don't see a checked radio item.

Answer (score 0):

Here is very simple way to make form validation using jquery

```js
// Wait for the DOM to be ready
$(function() {
  // Initialize form validation on the registration form.
  // It has the name attribute "registration"
  $("form[name='registration']").validate({
    // Specify validation rules
    rules: {
      // The key name on the left side is the name attribute
      // of an input field. Validation rules are defined
      // on the right side
      firstname: "required",
      lastname: "required",
      email: {
        required: true,
        // Specify that email should be validated
        // by the built-in "email" rule
        email: true
      },
      password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
      }
    },
    // Specify validation error messages
    messages: {
      firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
      lastname: "Please enter your lastname",

      password: {
        required: "Please provide a password",
        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
      },
      email: {
        required: "Please provide a valid user name",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address"
      }
    },
    // Make sure the form is submitted to the destination defined
    // in the "action" attribute of the form when valid
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans");

/* Styles */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 14px;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

form {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #2c3e50;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

form label,
form input,
form button {
  border: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

form input {
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0 6px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form button {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #e67e22;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.error {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js'></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Registration</h2>
  <form action="" name="registration">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="john@doe.com" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;" />
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate() {
    var scheduledOn = $("#ScheduledOn").val();
    var status = $(".Status option:selected").text();
    var result = true;

    if (id == "") {
        var scheduledOn = $("#ScheduledOn").val();
        var category = $(".categoryList option:selected").text();
        var activityTask = $(".activityTaskList option:selected").text();

        var lead = $("#LeadID").val();
        var agent = $("#AgentID").val();

        if (category == "Select Category") {
            $("#categoryValidation").show();
            $("#categoryValidation").text("The Category field is required");
        }
        else {
            $("#categoryValidation").hide();
        }

        if (category == "Agent Recruitment" || category == "Direct Sales" || category == "Joint Field Work" || category == "Select Category" || category == "Agent Development") {
            var activityTask = $(".activityTaskList option:selected").text();

            if (activityTask == "Select Activity Task") {
                $("#activityTaskValidation").show();
                $("#activityTaskValidation").text("The Activity Task field is required");
            }
            else {
                $("#activityTaskValidation").hide();
            }
        }

        if (category == "Joint Field Work") {
            if (agent == "" || agent == "Select Agent") {
                $("#agentValidation").show();
                $("#agentValidation").text("The Agent field is required");
                result = false;
            }
            else {
                $("#agentValidation").hide();
            }
        }

        if (category == "Joint Field Work") {
            if (lead == "" || lead == null || lead == "Select Lead") {
                $("#leadValidation").show();
                $("#leadValidation").text("The Lead field is required");
                result = false;
            }

            else {
                $("#leadValidation").hide();
            }
        }

        if (category == "Agent Recruitment" || category == "Agent Development") {
            if (agent == "" || agent == "Select Agent") {
                $("#agentValidation").show();
                $("#agentValidation").text("The Agent field is required");
                result = false;
            }
            else {
                $("#agentValidation").hide();
            }
        }

        if (category == "Direct Sales") {
            if (lead == "" || lead == "Select Lead" || lead == null) {
                $("#leadValidation").show();
                $("#leadValidation").text("The Lead field is required");
                result = false;
            }
            else {
                $("#leadValidation").hide();
            }
        }

        if (scheduledOn == "" || scheduledOn == null) {
            $("#scheduledOnValidation").show();
            $("#scheduledOnValidation").text("The Scheduled On field is required");
            result = false;
        }
        else if (Date.parse(scheduledOn) <= Date.now()) {
            $("#scheduledOnValidation").show();
            $("#scheduledOnValidation").text("The Scheduled On field should be greater than current date time");
            result = false;
        }
        else {
            $("#scheduledOnValidation").hide();
        }

        return result;
    }
    else {
        var scheduledOn = $("#NewScheduledOn").val();
        var status = $(".Status option:selected").text();

        if (document.getElementById("SetAppointment_Y").checked) {
            var activityTask = $(".activityTaskList").val();

            if (activityTask == null || activityTask == "") {
                $("#activityTaskValidation").show();
                $("#activityTaskValidation").text("The Activity Task field is required");
                result = false;
            }
            else {
                $("#activityTaskValidation").hide();
                $("#scheduledOnValidation").hide();
            }

            if (status != null && (scheduledOn == "" || scheduledOn == null)) {
                $("#scheduledOnValidation").show();
                $("#scheduledOnValidation").text("The Scheduled On field is required");
                $("#statusValidation").hide();
                result = false;
            }
            else if (Date.parse(scheduledOn) <= Date.now()) {
                $("#scheduledOnValidation").show();
                $("#scheduledOnValidation").text("The Scheduled On field should be greater than current date time");
                result = false;
            }
            else {
                $("#scheduledOnValidation").hide();
                $("#statusValidation").show();
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```